# OpenLayers Ext.form.ComboBox store query creates memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, combobox, openlayers, geoserver, jsonstore

Ack.   Using OpenLayers, I have an Ext.form.ComboBox that runs a query of a Ext.data.JsonStore to access a shapefile of ~1 Gb and return a table of results.  Then, a user may select one of the results and the map zooms to that location.

This works excellent.  BUT!  As the ComboBox is used, the JVM size continues to grow- a memory leak?- and Geoserver throws many issues mostly all related to:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
ERROR [geotools.map] - Call MapContent dispose() to prevent memory leaks
```

I can run the ComboBox as many as five times within about a minute before a storm of errors overwhelm Geoserver (e.g. GetFeatureInfo doesn't return any results, the ComboBox query comes back empty, pink tiles appear, EDIT: and GWC stops making new tiles!).

Do I need to destroy () or clear the store or...?  and how?  Thoughts??

GeoExt 1.1, OpenLayers 2.12.rc6, Ext 3.4, Ext 4.2.1.883, jquery-1.6, Geoserver 2.5, JDK i586 v7, Tomcat 7

code:

THE QUERY: looks up what is typed in the ComboBox & populates the Store

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
    doQuery: function(q, forceAll) {
        console.log('queryTpl', this.queryTpl, q); 
        q = Ext.isEmpty(q) ? '' : q;
        var qe = {
            query: q,
            forceAll: forceAll,
            combo: this,
            cancel: false
        };
        if (this.fireEvent('beforequery', qe) === false || qe.cancel) {
            return false;
        }
        q = qe.query;
        forceAll = qe.forceAll;
        if (forceAll === true || (q.length >= this.minChars)) {
            if (this.lastQuery !== q) {
                this.lastQuery = q;
                if (this.mode == 'local') {
                    this.selectedIndex = -1;
                    if (forceAll) {
                        this.store.clearFilter();
                    } else {
                        this.store.filter(this.displayField, q);
                    }
                    this.onLoad();
                } else {
                    this.store.baseParams[this.queryParam] = this.queryTpl ? String.format(this.queryTpl, q) : q;
                    this.store.load({
                        params: this.getParams(q)
                    });
                    this.expand();
                }
            } else {
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
                this.onLoad();
            }
        }
    },
});
})
```

THE STORE

```
var dsm = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
remoteFilter: true,
autoLoad: false,
autoDestroy: true,  // doesn't appear to help
url: '../geoserver/workspace',  // generalized, not for public access
storeId: 'myStore2',
baseParams: {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.1.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'MRDS_LUT',    // *shp in geoserver defined by var
    srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
    outputFormat: 'json',
    propertyName: 'SiteName,Municipal,Commodity,Status,Longitude,Latitude'
},
root: 'features',
fields: [{
    name: 'SiteName',
    mapping: 'properties.SiteName'
}, {
    name: 'Municipal',
    mapping: 'properties.Municipal'
}, {
    name: 'Commodity',
    mapping: 'properties.Commodity'
}, {
    name: 'Status',
    mapping: 'properties.Status'
}, {
    name: 'Longitude',
    mapping: 'properties.Longitude'
}, {
    name: 'Latitude',
    mapping: 'properties.Latitude'
},{
    name: 'bbox',
    mapping: 'properties.bbox'
}],
sortInfo: {
    field: "Municipal",
    direction: "ASC"
}
});
```

The ComboBox

```
var panelSiteNameSearch = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
store: dsm,
fieldLabel: "<b>Search</b>",
queryParam: "cql_filter",
queryTpl: "SiteName Like '{0}%'",
minChars: 5,
displayField: "SiteName",
valueField: "SiteName",
typeAhead: false,
loadingText: "Searching...",
width: 230,
emptyText: "Mine/Mineral Site Search",
hideTrigger: true,
tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="search-item"><b>Site Name:</b> {SiteName}<br><b>Commodity: </b> {Commodity}<br><b>Municipality:</b> {Municipal}<br><b>Status:</b> {Status}</div><hr/></tpl>',
itemSelector: "div.search-item",
    listeners: {
        "select": function (combo, record) {
            mrdsprimary.setVisibility(true);
            mrdssecondary.setVisibility(true);
            mrdstertiary.setVisibility(true);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(record.data.Longitude,record.data.Latitude),13);
        },
        "focus": function () {
            keyboardnav.deactivate();
        },
        "blur": function () {
            keyboardnav.activate();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added panelSiteNameSearch.store.removeAll(); just after map.setCenter, and I can now keep querying the store as much as I'd like, and the ComboBox works as it should regardless of JVM size **but all GetFeatureInfo and any layer utilizing GeoWebCache still completely stop working**

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit nebulous.  I finally prevented the out of memory errors by making sure the combined total size of all combo box stores, plus the initial Java -Xms allotment, does not exceed the Java -Xmx allotment.

For example, setting -Xms to 500m, and knowing that store #1 accesses a database of 600m and store #2 accesses a database of 800m, gives a combined total of 1900mb in my Java environment heap.  If the -Xmx is set to 2g, then no errors are thrown.

In theory.  I can't directly affect the Java environment's Xms without interfering (poorly) with Tomcat/Java's native GC.  Knowing there is total allotted -Xmx cap, and what counts directly toward it, encourages extremely trim data stores.

Unfortunately I am limited to a 32bit JDK i586, which I read somewhere that carries an inherent 2gb limitation for -Xmx (which seems about right).  The 64bit is reportedly much higher.

Findings: a remote store 'loads' an entire data store, and submits the filtered results locally... clearing the either store with removeAll or clearFilter or setValue() or NULL and/or SYNC only works locally and does not actually trigger any remote GC or reduction in the remote Java's heaping pile of unnecessary storage.

Long-term Solutions:  Create a server-side PHP script that passes a given cql or some other query or ComboBox value directly to a SQL or PostGIS database, and leave javascript out of it.  But I don't know how to write one yet.